# Register variable from ajax $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have what I hope is a successful post to my client's json API (in that it correctly sends data) but I'm having a very hard time grabbing that data and using it as a variable to update my site...

```
    $.post(takeurl, function(data) {            
        var newPrice = json.data.newPrice;
        alert('hi' );
    }, "json");

    $(this).parents("tr").find(".large-detail").html(newPrice);

    return false;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dilettante/8Jx78/)

Basically, in this example I want to update `large-detail` with the `newPrice` data from my API call, which is returned like this:

```
{"data":{"newPrice":80,"lockedInPrice":47},"errors":[],"success":true,"code":200}
```

Ideas?  I just can't get `newPrice` through.  I'm hoping I made a stupid syntax error, even if it'll make me feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update it in the callback function:

```
    var $self = $(this);

    $.getJSON(takeurl, function(data) {            
        var newPrice = data.data.newPrice;
        $self.parents("tr").find(".large-detail").html(newPrice);
    });

    return false;
});
```

Where you have it now it executes before the ajax function returns and outside of the scope of your `newPrice` variable.

Comment: Hmm, I tried it there and it's not working... doesn't return anything.  Can you tell if my .post call is written correctly? (I should have mentioned this is tabular data, and I stripped the tables out of the fiddle to trim it)

Comment: @dilettante Do you need to use POST or can you use GET? If you can use GET than you can use `getJSON` like in my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I just tried that and am still getting nothing.  Oddly, I just added    console.log(newPrice);   after declaring the variable and it's not appearing.  So I changed it to    console.log('hi); and nothing.  Is it possible it's not calling, even if my console window shows the data being returned?

Comment: @dilettante Do you have `json.data.newPrice` or `data.data.newPrice`? Try doing just `console.log(data);`

Comment: @dilettante Does `console.log(data)` show you anything useful?

Comment: It doesn't show anything... Nothing in my console except the response from the server.

Comment: @dilettante Hmm.. Strange. What if right before the `var newPrice` line you put `console.log('data', data);`

Comment: Not a thing! If I put a console.log('hghjkh') before the callback, it appears.  Must be an error in my call?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28051/discussion-between-dilettante-and-paulpro)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to an error in the JSON returned, which was prefixed with `<pre>` and `</pre>` code for testing by other engineers, but which returned a parseerror when I tried to work with it.  Thanks @paulpro.